# Can I force ANTL4 to read expected tokens instead of letting it guessing what kind of token it may be?

Tags: parsing, grammar, antlr4

I try to write a simple ANTLR4 grammar for parsing SRT subtitles files. I thought it will be an easy, introductory task, but I guess I must miss some point. But first things first --- the grammar:

```
grammar Srt;

file    :   subtitle (NL NL subtitle)* EOF;

subtitle:   SUBNO NL
            TSTAMP ' --> ' TSTAMP NL
            LINE (NL LINE)*;

TSTAMP  :   I99 ':' I59 ':' I59 ',' I999;
SUBNO   :   D09+;
NL      :   '\r'? '\n';
LINE    :   ~('\r'|'\n')+;

fragment I999   :   D09 D09 D09;
fragment I99    :   D09 D09;
fragment I59    :   D05 D09;
fragment D09    :   [0-9];
fragment D05    :   [0-5];
```

And here's a beginning of a SRT file where the problem stars:

```
1
00:00:20,000 --> 00:00:26,000
```

The error I get is:

```
line 2:0 mismatched input '00:00:20,000 --> 00:00:26,000' expecting TSTAMP
```

So it looks like the second line applied to the lexer rule `LINE` (as this is the longest token it could have been matched), however what I expect is to match the rule `TSTAMP` (and that's why it's defined before `LINE` rule in the grammar). My ANTLR4 knowledge is to weak at this point to tweak the grammar in a way, that lexer could try to match a subset on tokens depending on current position in **parser** rule. What I intend to achieve is to match `TSTAMP` and not `LINE`, as `TSTAMP` is in fact expected input. Maybe I could trick it with some lexer modes, but I can hardly believe it couldn't be written in a simpler way. Can it?

---

As CoronA suggested the trick was to defer the decision for `LINE` rule to the parser and this was the clue. I modified the grammar a bit more and now it parser subtitles smoothly:

```
grammar Srt;

file    :   subtitle (NL NL subtitle)* EOF;

subtitle:   SUBNO NL
            TSTAMP ' --> ' TSTAMP NL
            lines;

lines   :   line (NL line)*;
line    :   (LINECHAR | SUBNO | TSTAMP)*;

TSTAMP  :   I99 ':' I59 ':' I59 ',' I999;
SUBNO   :   D09+;
NL      :   '\r'? '\n';
LINECHAR:   ~[\r\n];

fragment I999   :   D09 D09 D09?;
fragment I99    :   D09 D09;
fragment I59    :   D05 D09;
fragment D09    :   [0-9];
fragment D05    :   [0-5];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of the token `LINE` subsumes everything:

```
LINE    :   ~('\r'|'\n')+;
```

Each `TSTAMP` is also a `LINE` but a line can match longer lexems. And it does as you can see. ANTLR prefers longest matches.

To make your grammar work, transfer the decision what a line is from the lexer into the parser:

```
subtitle:   SUBNO NL
            TSTAMP ' --> ' TSTAMP NL
            line*;

line:   (LINECHAR | TSTAMP | SUBNO)* NL?;

...

LINECHAR    :   ~('\r'|'\n' ) ; //remove the '+'
```

You can see that a line may contain any `LINE_CHAR` but also `TSTAMP`s and `SUBNO`s.

Comment: That's the problem — `LINE` could be actually everything and in fact it can (why not?) contain "tokens" like `TSTAMP` or any other. The structure is described in `subtitle` rule: `SUBNO NL TSTAMP ' --> ' TSTAMP NL LINE (NL LINE)*`. So line is "everything between NL-s", although it is expected after line with `TSTAMP`s. And as you can see, two `subtitle`s are separated with two NL-s. It is very easy to write a parser/lexer not using ANTLR4, but I start to believe it is not possible to encode (with ANTLR) a rule, where parser rule enforces certain lexer rule (depending on current context)?

Comment: I adjusted my suggestion. The trick is to defer the decision for `LINE` to the parser.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Although... Isn't there any possibility, knowing what shall come from input, to define a rule in a more brief way, like "read every char up to this one"? Currently line is being searched for tokens like TSTAMP or SUBNO, but knowing the meaning of incoming data, there's actually no point in trying to pluck these tokens from input.

Comment: There exist other parsers (PEG-Parsers like parboiled) that allow you such specifications. ANTLR does not (i.e. I do not know how to do it).

Comment: Thanks for this tip — seems like it's more appropriate tool for this case.